# Create Customer In PayPal

Tags: go, paypal

I was working on PayPal and wanted to know some things about PayPal that we can do in Stripe through Golang API:

1. can we create a customer through PayPal Go API and then attach card to it? Now What I have integrated is saved a card directly into PayPal vault and start transactions from the saved card. I have gone through the documentation of Go API and found no docs there about customer creation through API. [PayPal API Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/)
2. When we fill card details, is it possible we return a card nonce/token from the PayPal api so that the token represents all the card info?
3. Can I set a card to default card of the customer through PayPal Go API?

I need to know all of the above points through Go API. Can anyone guide me upon how can I do all of the above if is possible ??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "PayPal Go API", I don't see any official go sdk

Comment: @antham by paypal go api I mean third party sdk for paypal in golang. I am using https://github.com/logpacker/PayPal-Go-SDK sdk

Comment: I would say if you find nothing in api documentation, it means it's not possible

Answer (score -1):

From what I can gather you:

### Create the order with intent to CAPTURE

```
POST /v2/checkout/orders
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "1.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Then CAPTURE the order

```
POST /v2/checkout/orders/<OrderId>/capture
{
    "payment_source": {
     "token": {
       "id": "VAULT CARD ID HERE",
       "type": "PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKEN"
     }
   }
}
```

This is as far as I have gotten because I am getting a 500 error currently